# cakephp checkbox not remaining checked after submit

Tags: php, cakephp, checkbox

I have a question on cakephp Form (checkbox) attribute. When I use the following code to generate a page with multiple input checkboxes and after checking some checkboxes when I hit submit button I get a refreshed page with those checkboxes remained checked. That's good.

```
$options = array("one"=>"one", "two"=>"two");
echo $this->Form->create('Pres');
echo $this->Form->input('Name',array(
    'label' => false,
    'type' => 'select',
    'multiple' => 'checkbox',
    'options' => $options,
));
echo $this->Form->end("Submit");
```

But when I generate the page with the following code, the refreshed page after submit does not keep those checked boxes checked

```
echo $this->Form->create('Pres');
echo $this->Form->input('Name.',array('type'=>'checkbox','hiddenField'=>false,'label'=>'one','value'=>'one'));
echo $this->Form->input('Name.',array('type'=>'checkbox','hiddenField'=>false,'label'=>'two','value'=>'two'));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
```

I want to use second approach for some particular reason, but after submit, I would like to have the refreshed page with those checkboxes remain checked. Greatly appreciate your input.

Comment: Why You are using field name `Name.` with dot?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how CakePHP works about that, but it could need the first approach to associate the checked status to each checkbox with the `$options` array at once. So on the second approach CakePHP gets multiples input(checkbox) and doesn't know where his `$options` list is to check the right ones.

If you need the second approach for a particular reason, I suggest you still use the first approach, then change what you need after render with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Your checkboxes in first approach remain checked in your first approach..strange may be due browser caching but after you refreshing your page you have to make them checked by adding "checked" => 'checked' attritbute in both approaches.

```
Example:
echo $this->Form->input('Name.',
                        array('type'=>'checkbox',
                              'hiddenField'=>false,
                              'label'=>'two',
                              'value'=>'two',
                              **'checked' => 'checked'**));
```

Hope this will help you!